# C: Count the actual size of an int-type array

Tags: c, arrays, int, sizeof

### I'm having problem getting the *actual size* of an *int-type* array.

*Note: I got no problem with char-type arrays, I got the output I expect.*

Example, having this declaration, `int arr[3]` and using `sizeof(arr)` will have an output that will surely vary, it could be 3, 6, 12, etc... depending on the bit-system. 
So how will then I get the actual size of my array on a code like this: [Ideone Code Here](http://ideone.com/2p1wO1)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int countSize[3]={1,2,3};

int main() {
    printf("%d",sizeof(countSize));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Divide the value by the size of the elements - **sizeof(countSize)/sizeof(countSize[0])**

Comment: What does it print? What, exactly, is the proble ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like by *actual size*, you mean the elements of the array. Since `sizeof(countSize)` gives the size of the array in bytes, all you need is to divide it by the size of each element like this:

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(countSize) / sizeof(int));
```

Or better, use `sizeof(countSize[0]` as the type of the array may vary:

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(countSize) / sizeof(countSize[0]));
```

You got expected result when working with `char` arrays because `sizeof(char)` is always `1`.